Is it reasonable to use induction to justify belief in the existence of other minds?
Is it reasonable to use an argument by analogy (induction) to justify belief in the existence of other minds?
The principle of the uniformity of nature is used in the argument by analogy.
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#ArguAnal
It says that using an argument by analogy to justify the existence of other minds inevitably leads to solipsism. What does it mean? How can an argument for the existence of other minds lead to solipsism?
Is it reasonable to use the principle of the uniformity of nature to justify the belief in the existence of other minds?
Or is it better instead of using the principle of uniformity in an argument by analogy to use the principle of uniformity in an abductive argument?

It is Inference to the Best Explanation

Is it reasonable to keep asking the question in the same place? Maybe we don't know the answer.
